# Java Sort Maps by Values of Some Keys

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

How to I implement a `Comparator` to sort a List of Maps by certain key values? My goal is to sort two Lists arbitrarily so that I can compare the other fields that are not part of the sorting.

For example, given that I have these two list of maps, I want to sort by firstName and lastName.

```
+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
| List 1    | Map 1  | Map 2 | Map 3 |
+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
| firstName | John   | Eric  | John  |
| lastName  | Miller | Smith | Davis |
| age       | 17     | 19    | 35    |
+-----------+--------+-------+-------+

+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
|  List 2   | Map 1  | Map 2 | Map 3 |
+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
| firstName | Eric   | John  | John  |
| lastName  | Smith  | Davis | Miller|
| age       | 53     | 38    | 26    |
+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
```

And after I sort it, now I can compare Map 1 of List 1 to Map 2 of List 2 and see what's different.

So I have a class that implements the comparator like so:

```
// Note that the values may not implement Comparable
public class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Map<String, Object>> {
    private List<String> sortKeys = Arrays.asList("firstName", "lastName");

    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String, Object> map1, Map<String, Object> map2) {
        Map<String, Object> keyValue1 = new HashMap<>();
        sortKeys.forEach(key -> keyValue1.put(key, map1.get(key)));

        Map<String, Object> keyValue2 = new HashMap<>();
        sortKeys.forEach(key -> keyValue2.put(key, map2.get(key)));

        return keyValue2.hashCode() - keyValue1.hashCode();
    }
}
```

And calling `sort` on each of the lists will result in the following:

```
+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
| List 1    | Map 1  | Map 2 | Map 3 |
+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
| firstName | John   | Eric  | John  |
| lastName  | Miller | Smith | Davis |
| age       | 17     | 19    | 35    |
+-----------+--------+-------+-------+

+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
| List 2    | Map 1  | Map 2 | Map 3 |
+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
| firstName | John   | Eric  | John  |
| lastName  | Miller | Smith | Davis |
| age       | 26     | 53    | 38    |
+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
```

But the order of the lists never changes... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that this line has any meaning? What do you think that it does? `return keyValue2.hashCode() - keyValue1.hashCode();`

Comment: What is the structure of the `Map`s' entries? Why are there `Map`s in the list, there should be `Person`s.

Comment: The maps could have different fields. So Map1 could be the only one that has address field, or Map2 could be the only one with birthday field. Pojos are not an option when the structure is not know or consistent. Only the keys I specify are guaranteed to be available.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, your sorting is based on the key's hash codes - an ordering that doesn't necessarily correlate to their values (i.e., a "smaller" string can have a larger hash code and vice versa).

Instead, you should sort according to the values themselves, even if it means explicitly casting the `Object` values you have to comparables:

```
Comparator<Map<String, Object>> personComparator =
    Comparator.comparing(m -> (String) m.get("firstName"))
              .thenComparing(m -> (String) m.get("lastName"));
```

Comment: The size of the string is irrelevant as I said I just wanted to sort arbitrarily. The only thing I need is a consistent sort order based on a portion of the Map vs the entire Map, or I could have used `Entry. comparingByValue()`. I think the `hashCode` can be used to make the compare method return 0 when they are equal, although sometimes this can happen with unequal values as well.

Comment: It doesn't matter that string A is smaller or greater than string B, as long as it's consistent. I need to sort so that the keys I specify line up with the other sorted list.